# Track object lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, profiling

I have a spring context with several spring bean services. I'm passing an instantiated object reference across many services. How can I analyze various metrics, such as the time it takes to pass the object from one service to another, number of services that the object is passed to, etc.? I consider this to be a bit more advanced than simple profiling because I want to be able to track the object, not just service method invocations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some clever profiler by yourself:

- add wrapper class for profiled object with additional field for profiling information
- create as set of `AspectJ` interceptors to fill profiling information (for example increment `numberOfServiceCalls`
- put created aspects on services